# I need to change the natbib package to version 8.31

Tags: natbib

I want to submit a programme `.tex` to ArXiv.
At present, I have an error, which is fairly documented.
I need to change package `natbib` to a more recent version that is natbib 8.31,
If you could explain me, where are stored the packages, in TexShop, I could patch the former `natbib` to the new one!

Comment: TeXshop is a front-end, but presumably you have a 'TeX system' such as MacTeX installed. Assuming that is the case, exactly which one do you have? MacTeX is the most common, and there is a release each year. The best way to tackle your problem depends on exactly what you have set up.